# Need help regarding on back button press load pop dialog from diffrent Activity

Tags: android

**MainAcivity.java**

```
package com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.Activity.DetailsActivity;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.Activity.SettingSectioned;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.Adapters.CategoryAdapter;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.AnimalSound.AnimalSoundDetailsActivity;

//******************************* Add Activity Here ***********************************************
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.CategoryAlphabetsThemes.CategoryAlphabetsDetailsActivity;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.CategoryAlphabetsPhonics.CategoryAlphabetsphonicsDetailsActivity;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.CategoryNumbers.CategoryNumbersDetailsActivity;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.CategoryAnimals.CategoryAnimalsDetailsActivity;

//******************************* End ***********************************************

import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.Database.DatabaseHelper;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.Models.MainCategoryModel;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.Models.itemsModel;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.Quiz.javafile.GameCompleteDialog;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.Quiz.javafile.QuizQuestionHandler;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.Quiz.logo_quiz.QuizActivity;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.TextQuiz.QuestionActivity;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.Utils.SharedPref;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.drawing.DrawingActivity;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.drawing.ResourcePool;
import com.yashoaryasoftinc.learnbook.drawingboard.activity.DrawBoardActivity;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static final String INTENT_KEY = "Select Level";
    ImageView BtnHome;
    LinearLayout Draw_Alphabets;
    LinearLayout Draw_Numbers;
    ImageView ImageViewAds;
    LinearLayout Layout_DrawBoard;
    LinearLayout Layout_animalSound;

//******************************* Sound Related Item ***********************************************
    LinearLayout Layout_Animals;
    LinearLayout Layout_Alphabets;

    LinearLayout Layout_Numbers;
    LinearLayout Layout_Alphabetsphonics;

//******************************* End **************************************************************

    LinearLayout Layout_image_quiz;
    LinearLayout Layout_text_quiz;
    ImageView RateApp;
    ImageView Settings;

    private List<MainCategoryModel> data;
    private itemsModel data2;
    private DatabaseHelper db;
    RelativeLayout gdprLayout;
    private CategoryAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    Dialog myDialog;
    SharedPreferences prefs = null;
    SharedPref sharedpref;
    private TextView titlebar;



    
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        AdAdmob adAdmob = new AdAdmob( this);
        adAdmob.BannerAd((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner), this);
        //adAdmob.FullscreenAd_Counter(this);
        QuizQuestionHandler.populateList();
        this.myDialog = new Dialog(this);
        this.gdprLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gdprLayout);
        init();
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        this.db = databaseHelper;
        databaseHelper.openDataBase();
        this.data = this.db.getCategorieList();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.conversation_rv);
        this.mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        this.mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        this.mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, R.layout.category_list_layout, this.data);
        this.mAdapter = categoryAdapter;
        this.mRecyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
        this.mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new CategoryAdapter.OnItemClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onItemClick(View view, MainCategoryModel mainCategoryModel, int i) {
                MainCategoryModel mainCategoryModel2 = (MainCategoryModel) MainActivity.this.data.get(i);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Category", mainCategoryModel2.getCategory_name());
                intent.putExtra("id", mainCategoryModel2.getId());
                String GetSaveChoice = SettingSectioned.GetSaveChoice(MainActivity.this);
                GetSaveChoice.hashCode();
                if (GetSaveChoice.equals("English")) {
                    intent.putExtra("Category_Desc", mainCategoryModel2.getCategory_eng());
                } else if (GetSaveChoice.equals("Arabic")) {
                    intent.putExtra("Category_Desc", mainCategoryModel2.getCategory_ar());
                } else {
                    intent.putExtra("Category_Desc", mainCategoryModel2.getCategory_eng());
                }
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    
    public void clearTcfData(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences defaultSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Object[] array = defaultSharedPreferences.getAll().keySet().toArray();
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        for (Object obj : array) {
            if (obj.toString().compareToIgnoreCase("IABTCF_TCString") == 0) {
                arrayList.add(obj.toString());
            }
        }
        if (!arrayList.isEmpty()) {
            Iterator it = arrayList.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                defaultSharedPreferences.edit().remove((String) it.next()).apply();
            }
        }
        Log.v("tag", String.valueOf(array));
    }

    private void init() {

        this.Draw_Alphabets = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout_Draw_Alphabets);
        this.Draw_Alphabets.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.Draw_Numbers = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout_Draw_Numbers);
        this.Draw_Numbers.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.Layout_animalSound = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout_animalSound);
        this.Layout_animalSound.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.Layout_image_quiz = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout_image_quiz);
        this.Layout_image_quiz.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.RateApp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rateApp);
        this.RateApp.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.Settings = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_settings);
        this.Settings.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.BtnHome = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_home);
        this.BtnHome.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.Layout_text_quiz = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout_text_quiz);
        this.Layout_text_quiz.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.Layout_DrawBoard = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout_DrawBoard);
        this.Layout_DrawBoard.setOnClickListener(this);

//******************************* Sound Related Item ***********************************************

        this.Layout_Animals = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout_Animals);
        this.Layout_Animals.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.Layout_Alphabets = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout_Alphabets);
        this.Layout_Alphabets.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.Layout_Numbers = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout_Numbers);
        this.Layout_Numbers.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.Layout_Alphabetsphonics = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout_Alphabetsphonics);
        this.Layout_Alphabetsphonics.setOnClickListener(this);

//******************************* End ***********************************************

    }

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        switch (id) {

            case R.id.btn_home :
                new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getParent() + "/shared_prefs/__GOOGLE_FUNDING_CHOICE_SDK_INTERNAL__.xml").delete();
                clearTcfData(this);

                return;
            case R.id.main_settings :
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingSectioned.class));
                return;
            case R.id.rateApp :
                ShowRateDialog();
                return;
            default:
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.Layout_DrawBoard :
                        if (isInternetAvailable()) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DrawBoardActivity.class));
                            return;
                        } else {
                            DialogConx();
                            return;
                        }
                    case R.id.Layout_Draw_Alphabets :
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DrawingActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("type", ResourcePool.DRAWING_ALPHABET);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return;
                    case R.id.Layout_Draw_Numbers :
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DrawingActivity.class);
                        intent2.putExtra("type", ResourcePool.NUMBER);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                        return;
                    case R.id.Layout_animalSound :
                        if (isInternetAvailable()) {
                            ShowAnimalChoiceDialog();
                            return;
                        } else {
                            DialogConx();
                            return;
                        }

//******************************* Sound with Dialog Box *****************************************

                    case R.id.Layout_Animals :
                        if (isInternetAvailable()) {
                            ShowAnimalsChoiceDialog();
                            return;
                        } else {
                            DialogConx();
                            return;
                        }
                    case R.id.Layout_Alphabets :
                        if (isInternetAvailable()) {
                            ShowAlphabetsChoiceDialog();
                            return;
                        } else {
                            DialogConx();
                            return;
                        }
                    case R.id.Layout_Numbers :
                        if (isInternetAvailable()) {
                            ShowNumbersChoiceDialog();
                            return;
                        } else {
                            DialogConx();
                            return;
                        }
                    case R.id.Layout_Alphabetsphonics :
                        if (isInternetAvailable()) {
                            ShowAlphabetsphonicsChoiceDialog();
                            return;
                        } else {
                            DialogConx();
                            return;
                        }

                    case R.id.Layout_image_quiz :
                        if (isInternetAvailable()) {
                            Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuizActivity.class);
                            QuizQuestionHandler.populateList();
                            QuizActivity.timer = 200;
                            QuizActivity.QUESTION_LIMIT = 25;
                            GameCompleteDialog.Score = 18;
                            startActivity(intent3);
                            return;
                        }
                        DialogConx();
                        return;
                    case R.id.Layout_text_quiz :
                        if (isInternetAvailable()) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuestionActivity.class));
                            return;
                        } else {
                            DialogConx();
                            return;
                        }
                    default:
                        return;
                }
        }
    }

    public void ShowRateDialog() {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        this.myDialog = dialog;
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.rate_dialog);
        TextView textView = (TextView) this.myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtclose);
        textView.setText("X");
        ((Button) this.myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnfollow)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
                intent.addFlags(1208483840);
                try {
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException unused) {
                    MainActivity mainActivity = MainActivity.this;
                    mainActivity.startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
                }
            }
        });
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MainActivity.this.myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        this.myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        this.myDialog.show();
    }
    
      public void ShowAlphabetsChoiceDialog() {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        this.myDialog = dialog;
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alphabets_dialog);
        TextView textView = (TextView) this.myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtclose);
        textView.setText("Close");
        ((LinearLayout) this.myDialog.findViewById(R.id.alphabetsletters)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), CategoryAlphabetsDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", 1);
                intent.putExtra("category", "Alphabets Letters");
                intent.putExtra("desc", "الحيوانات البرية");
                intent.putExtra("desc_eng", "Animaux Sauvages");
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        ((LinearLayout) this.myDialog.findViewById(R.id.uppercaseletters)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), CategoryAlphabetsDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", 2);
                intent.putExtra("category", "Uppercase Letters");
                intent.putExtra("desc", "الحيوانات الأليفة");
                intent.putExtra("desc_eng", "Animaux domestiques");
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        ((LinearLayout) this.myDialog.findViewById(R.id.lowercaseletters)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), CategoryAlphabetsDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", 3);
                intent.putExtra("category", "Lowercase Letters");
                intent.putExtra("desc", "حيوانات المزرعة");
                intent.putExtra("desc_eng", "Animaux de Ferme");
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        ((LinearLayout) this.myDialog.findViewById(R.id.consonantsandvowels)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), CategoryAlphabetsDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", 4);
                intent.putExtra("category", "Consonants & Vowels");
                intent.putExtra("desc", "الطيور");
                intent.putExtra("desc_eng", "Les Oiseaux");
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        ((LinearLayout) this.myDialog.findViewById(R.id.alphabetsphonics)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), CategoryAlphabetsDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", 5);
                intent.putExtra("category", "Alphabets Phonics");
                intent.putExtra("desc", "الطيور");
                intent.putExtra("desc_eng", "Les Oiseaux");
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MainActivity.this.myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        this.myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        this.myDialog.show();
    }
        public void DialogConx() {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        this.myDialog = dialog;
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_cnx);
        TextView textView = (TextView) this.myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtclose);
        textView.setText("X");
        ((Button) this.myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnLater)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MainActivity.this.myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MainActivity.this.myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        this.myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        this.myDialog.show();
    }

    public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = ((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }



    
    @Override 
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    
    @Override 
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }



    @Override 
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Dialog dialog = this.myDialog;
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            this.myDialog = null;
        }
    }



    @Override 
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finishAffinity();
    }
}
```

[Step 1 Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9V9J.png)

[Step 2 After Clicking alphabet button from Main Activity it open this dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGm7k.jpg)

[Step 3 goes to Alphabet Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAgoO.jpg)

[Step 4 After Clicking back button from alphabet activity load Dialog from Main activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BtcN.jpg)

**CategoryAlphabetsDetailsActivity.java**

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (this.songPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            this.songPlayer.stop();
        }
        finish();
    }
```

What I want: After clicking on `CategoryAlphabetsDetailsActivity.java` **onBackPressed** it should load "ShowAlphabetsChoiceDialog" from `MainActivity.java`